# Button Click event in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to fire a button click event in angular Js but its not happening at all. Neither i am getting any kind of event related error in developer console of Chrome.
Here is the Markup..

```
                    <!-- Login Form Here !-->

                    <div id="login" ng-controller="LoginformController" style="display: none;" class="col-sm-5 form-box">
                        <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-top-left">
                                <h3>Login now</h3>
                                <p>Fill in the form below to get instant access:</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-top-right">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-top-divider"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-bottom">
                            <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="registration-form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="UserID">User ID</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="UserID" placeholder="User ID..." class="form-first-name form-control" id="UserID">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="Password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-last-name form-control" id="Password">
                                </div>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn">Login!</button>
                                <br/>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-link" ng-click="PasswordRecovery()">Forgot Password</button>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and here is the anguar JS code..

```
  var app = angular.module('LoginApp', []);
  app.controller('LoginformController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.PasswordRecovery = function () {
                alert("Clicked 2");

            }
        });
```

Please help me to resolve this ..

Comment: Why `style="display: none;"` on `div`, you can remove that

Comment: try to console.log something inside the controller...can u see the result??

Comment: @Tushar I want to show that controller after button click but i am not able to fire click event only ..Once click get fired i will make that Show()

Comment: Make sure you dint prevent your chrome from firing alerts

Comment: Do you have `ng-app="LoginApp"` somewhere above in your html?

Comment: @Andrey yes its there in the body of the page

Comment: can you provide plunker, fiddle etc ?

Comment: @Vanojx1 I am getting console error as `Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/ng/areq?p0=SignupformController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined`

Comment: You have an error in your code somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I would add

```
<div ng-controller="UnexistingController"></div>
```

to your HTML then I would get:

> "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'UnexistingController' is not a function,
>   got undefined
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/areq?p0=UnexistingController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Which makes sense, since I did not add a controller to the module yet. I suspect you made the same mistake.

> Argument 'SignupformController' is not a f‌​unction, got undefined
>
> **Description**
>
> AngularJS often asserts that certain values will be present and truthy
>   using a helper function. If the assertion fails, this error is thrown.
>   To fix this problem, make sure that the value the assertion expects **is
>   defined** and truthy

.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, I don't understand why you added  `style="display: none;`, but it's not the problem.

[See Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/WiLp92vYd2YUJrGpj6C8?p=preview)